# Know if one or more checkboxes are checked in Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Is there a way in jQuery to know if at least one checkbox has been checked?

I have a form with a lot of checkboxes and each one is different.

I need a way with jQuery to say something like this, this is the logic:

```
If at least one of the checkboxes in this specific form has been checked, then DO THIS else DO THAT.
```

I repeat each checkbox has a different name, id and value. So I need something generic.

Instead the form is only one and the ID is `#tuitting_form`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).read(function(){

 $("#tuitting_form input:checkbox").live('click', function(){

    if( $("#tuitting_form input:checkbox:checked").length > 0){
       $("#send_message").show(); $("#remove_accounts").show(); 
    }

 });
});
```

Comment: Make sure the js is well formed

Comment: if( $("#tuitting_form input:checkbox:checked").length){ }

Comment: Yes thanks. But the result is the same. The form is called by AJAX from another page. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Can you explain the problem in detail?

Comment: It does not do what is supposed to do without giving any error. The form is shown in the page thanks to an AJAX call. The form shows in the page through an AJAX call. So I am wondering if it could be the problem. Maybe the code you have shown above cannot declare the checkboxes inside this form because it comes from an AJAX call. Could it be the issue?

Comment: This is the code I am trying to use    if($("#tuitting_form input:checkbox:checked").length > 0){
$("#send_message").show();
$("#remove_accounts").show();
}

Comment: After you show the form using AJAX call what do you do? When are you using $("#tuitting_form input:checkbox:checked").length?

Comment: Can you post some part of that code to get clear picture of what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I use your code in the page where the AJAX results show. So for example the form is in the page form.php. The page where the AJAX code and your code is index.php. After having loaded the form in index.php with AJAX, when someone clicks on a checkbox inside that form, some other elements should show up, as explained in the code above, but simply nothing happens =(

Comment: In that case you have to use live to attach event handlers. Please check my edited answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#form input:checked').length > 0)  //...
```

Comment: This will also count radio buttons.

Comment: Yes this will count radio buttons too.